# Unable to run Appium tests using Appium run-time 1.6.4

Tags: appium, appium-ios

Below is my set-up
1. Appium Server 1.6.6-beta.2

with this set-up tests are failing with following error message:

> Blockquote`[debug] [iOSSim] Killing all iOS Simulators
>   [debug] [iOSSim] Using fkill to kill processes: 285
>   [XCUITest] AggregateError: 
>       Error: Killing process 285 failed: Operation not permitted
>           at Promise.all.then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/fkill/index.js:41:10)
>       at AggregateError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/aggregate-error/index.js:19:3)
>       at Promise.all.then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/fkill/index.js:41:10)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
>    { AggregateError: 
>       Error: Killing process 285 failed: Operation not permitted
>           at Promise.all.then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/fkill/index.js:41:10)
>       at AggregateError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/aggregate-error/index.js:19:3)
>       at Promise.all.then`

But tests are running all fine with old Appium IDE Version 1.5.3 (Ara), available on same machine macOs Sierra 10.12.3

Could you please advise me what needs to be corrected?

Many thanks

more tracelog at below gist:
[gist.github.com/anonymous/bfb8464c0388b7bfdba567dba5f0e36a](http://gist.github.com/anonymous/bfb8464c0388b7bfdba567dba5f0e36a)

Comment: what is your xcode version

Comment: 8.3.1 (8E1000a)

Comment: Kindly refer more stacktrace at below gist: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bfb8464c0388b7bfdba567dba5f0e36a

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you updated appium from 1.5.3 to 1.6.4?

appium 1.6 and greater version are used to automate iOS10 and greater and there is a version compatibility issue you might face.

Answer (score 0):

Its clear from stack trace what is the issue:

`org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Can't locate an element by this strategy: By.name: Create a photo book`

You are using not-supported locator strategy `By.name`. Appium server 1.5.0 release note: [Remove long-deprecated name locator strategy](https://github.com/appium/appium/releases/tag/v1.5.0)